# Accessing Public Objects through the Object type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

#### Goal and problem

In order to export user entries to an `XML` file, I build a table with the list of all objects needed. There are `Textboxes`, `Checkboxes`, etc., but also "internal" objects such as `Double` or `Boolean`.

For the objects present in the Visual Studio Toolbox (i.e the `Textboxes` and `Checkboxes`) everything goes fine, but for the "internal" objects not.

Here is how I do.

#### 1. Making the list of objects

`tableSave` is the `DataTable` where my the list is located. Each line correspond to an object to save. They are added in the following manner:

```
AddSaveObject("Category", "Subcategory", "Name", ObjectToSave)
```

with

```
Private Sub AddSaveObject(Category As String, Subcategory As String, _
                          Name As String, ObjectToSave As Object)
    Dim newRow As DataRow = tableSave.NewRow()
    Dim columnValuesArray() As Object = New Object() {Category, Subcategory, Name, ObjectToSave}
    newRow.ItemArray = columnValuesArray
    tableSave.Rows.Add(newRow)
End Sub
```

#### 2. Writing to XML

I then write everything in my `XML` file. According the the `ObjectToSave` type, different actions are taken:

```
Select Case ObjectToSave.GetType
    Case GetType(CheckBox)
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.Checked.ToString
    Case GetType(Boolean)
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.ToString
    Case GetType(Double)
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.ToString
    Case GetType(...)
        ...
    Case Else 'for Textboxes etc.
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.text
End Select
```

#### Question

In the case of `Boolean`, `Double`, `String`, or other self-defined classes, the `ObjectToSave` is always empty, returning `0` or `""`.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

#### Answer

I've been able to solve my problem thanks to the answer of *varocarbas*. Here was the trick:

I am using a `For` to advance into the table. For each line, I was defining

```
Dim ObjectToSave As Object = tableSave.Rows(i).Item("Object")
```

Removing the As Object allows the so called ObjectToSave to be assigned the right type.

```
Dim ObjectToSave = tableSave.Rows(i).Item("Object")
```

What I still don't understand, though, is why it was not working, *only* with the "internal" objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a code which should deliver what you are after:

```
Dim ObjectToSave = GetType(Double) 'GetType(CheckBox) 
Select Case ObjectToSave
    Case GetType(CheckBox)
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.Checked.ToString
    Case GetType(Boolean)
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.ToString
    Case GetType(Double)
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.ToString
    Case GetType(...)
        ...
    Case Else 'for Textboxes etc.
        ValueToWrite = ObjectToSave.text
End Select
```